# inject fail by using Ninject.Web.Mvc in my MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject.web.mvc

I have a class like this:

```
public class UrlHelperFacade:UrlHelper
{
    public UrlHelperFacade(RequestContext requestContext) : base(requestContext) 
    { 
    }

    public UrlHelperFacade(RequestContext requestContext, RouteCollection routeCollection):base(requestContext,routeCollection) 
    { 
    }

    public new virtual bool IsLocalUrl(string url)
    {
        return base.IsLocalUrl(url);
    }
}
```

And I use the NInject to bind this class in global.asax:

```
 protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<UrlHelper>().To<UrlHelperFacade>();
        return kernel;
    }
```

then I inject in my controller:
 [Inject]
 public new UrlHelperFacade Url { get; set; }

when I use the property Url, I can get the instance,but fail ,when call the method:"IsLocalUrl",

**Here is the errors:**

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> **Stack trace:**
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.IsLocalUrl(String url)
>
> at CARESTREAM.RISGC.RISLite.Framework.UrlHelperFacade.IsLocalUrl(String url) in d:\Projects\GCRIS\SRC\Web\RISLite\CARESTREAM.RISGC.RISLite.Framework\Utility\UrlHelperFacade.cs:line 23
>
> at CARESTREAM.RISGC.RISLite.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(LogOnModel model, String returnUrl) in d:\Projects\GCRIS\SRC\Web\RISLite\CARESTREAM.RISGC.RISLite.Controllers\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 76
>
> at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass13.b*_10()
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)

I notice that the requestContext's member HttpContext and RouteData are null. Is that anyway to handle this? I just want to wapper the UrlHelper to make a unit test.

Comment: Why not use extension method?

Comment: Also, since your `stacktrace` doesn't mention `Ninject` at all, please post all `global.asax` functions that has to do with Ninject/Binding/DependecyResolving

Comment: here are code: `public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
    {
        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            kernel.Bind<UrlHelper>().To<UrlHelperFacade>();
            return kernel;
        }`